# How can I get the browser's local timezone using Rust js_sys?

Tags: rust, rust-wasm

I am using the `js_sys` crate to run some Rust code in the browser.

Having difficulty to understand how to use [`Intl::DateTimeFormat`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/Intl/struct.DateTimeFormat.html).

All I want is to get the local timezone, which is done with this JS code:

```
const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
```

This does not seem to work in Rust:

```
let tz = Intl::DateTimeFormat().resolved_options().time_zone();

  --> src/lib.rs:14:14
   |
14 |     let tz = Intl::DateTimeFormat().resolved_options().time_zone();
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ did you mean `Intl::DateTimeFormat { /* fields */ }`?
```

It seems to want me to create a new `DateTimeFormat` struct, but I just want to get the "default" one, if there's such thing...

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried passing empty for both arguments to `DateTimeFormat::new()`?

Comment: @SOFe that could help, but then `resolved_options()` seems to return `Object` and then I cannot get `time_zone` from it. Any idea?

Comment: Also, `::new()` has this error: `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 2 parameters`

Comment: I mean pass empty array and empty object for both arguments.

Comment: As for getting `time_zone` from `Object`, use `Reflect::get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@pauan](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/275#issuecomment-625156630), and as suggested by @SOFe in the comments, here's how to do it:

```
let options = Intl::DateTimeFormat::new(&Array::new(), &Object::new())
        .resolved_options();

let tz = Reflect::get(&options, &JsValue::from("timeZone"))
        .expect("Cannot get timeZone")
        .as_string()
        .expect("timeZone is not a String");
```